# iPhone project - collect files into one place

Tags: iphone, xcode

Sorry if this has been answered before but all my searches do not return anything related to this.

Is there a way to collect all the files referenced in a project and save them in the procject folder automatically? Rather that having links to places where you may accidentally delete the files.

Thanks,

Eds

Comment: Why did you not create all files referenced to the project in the same folder ?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode doesn't have a particular feature to support this, but when you add items to your Xcode project it does give you the option to copy those items to the project directory. Otherwise you need to manually copy the items to a common location.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean collect all the files? Do you mean your external files or class files. Your external files like images or audio/video files should be added into Resources directory, it does not matter where is the root directory of these files. Then, you can access with their name in the project.